# How to fix python module error when using openHAB

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, openhab

I am trying to use python with my Raspberry Pi 3 to toggle some LED lights I have using openHAB. The problem is when I try to run the python code I get an error and can't figure out what the cause it.

My python is

```
from openhab import openHAB

base_url = 'http://<ip>:8080/rest'

items = openhab.fetch_all_items()

print("Finished")
```

When I run the code I it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/Desktop/Test.py", line 1, in <module>
from openhab import openHAB
ImportError: No module named 'openhab'
```

When I use python 2.7 I get this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/pi/Desktop/Test.py", line 1, in 
>       from openhab import openHAB
>     File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openhab/**init**.py", line 1, in 
>       from .client import openHAB, OpenHAB
>     File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openhab/client.py", line 40
>       def **init**(self, base_url: str,
>                                  ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I've tried searching google but can't find any solutions that have worked for me.

I have installed openHAB and [Python openHAB](https://pypi.org/project/python-openhab/) on my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Make sure that the copy of Python that you installed Python openHAB into is the same one that you're using to run your code.  Having two versions of Python is the only explanation I can think of for the behavior you're describing.  So make sure that if you install with /xxx/yyy/bin/pip, you're running your code with /xxx/yyy/bin/python.

Comment: @Steve I tried using Python 2.7 and got the error I edited into the question. (I didn't know where to figure out what python versions they were so I downgraded to the next version on the pi)

Comment: My suggestion might still apply.  You think you know you're using a specific "Python 2.7" for all operations.  Are you sure you only have a single version of Python on your Pi?  Maybe you do.  I'm just suggesting that you make sure.  Sometimes a programmer doesn't realize he has two versions of Python involved, and this sort of problem results.  It's not the versions involved.  It's simply that you're installing a package into one Python installation, but running with a different one.

Comment: @Steve According to the Python-openHAB it requires "python >= 3.5" I'm using the Python 3.5.3 Shell to run the code.